# Java Incompatible types: inputstream cannot be converted to scanner

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner, inputstream

Whe I try to execute the program using this code I get the Incompatible types inputstream cannot be converted to scanner error. Where could the problem be?

```
private ArrayList<Student> readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
            readOnCampusStudent (in) ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            //info.add(type, id, lname, fname, resstat, prfee, credits);
            String fName = "p02-students.txt";
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fName));
            String studentType;
            while (in.hasNext()) {
               // studentList.add(type, id, lname, fname, resstat, prfee, credits);
                if ("C".equals(in.next())) {
                    studentList.add(readOnCampusStudent(in));
                }
                studentList.add(readOnlineStudent(in));
                in.nextLine();
            }
            in.close();
            return studentList;
        }
```

The program has four classes

## MainClass

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Main().run();
        }

        private onlineStudent readOnlineStudent(Scanner pIn) {
            int id;
            String lname, fname;
            id = pIn.nextInt();
            lname = pIn.next();
            fname = pIn.next();
            onlineStudent OnlineStudent = new onlineStudent(id, fname, lname) {
                @Override
                public void calcTuition()
                {
                }           
            };
            return OnlineStudent;
        }

        private void calcTuition(ArrayList<Student> pStudentList) {
            for (Student s : pStudentList) {
                s.calcTuition();
            }
        }

        private void run() {
            ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            try {
                studentList = readFile();
                calcTuition(studentList);
                Sorter.insertionSort(studentList, Sorter.SORT_ASCENDING);
                writeFile(studentList);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Sorry, could not open 'p02-students.txt' for reading.");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

        private onCampusStudent readOnCampusStudent(Scanner pIn) {
            int id = pIn.nextInt();
            String lname = pIn.next();
            String fname = pIn.next();
            onCampusStudent OnCampusStudent = new onCampusStudent(id, fname, lname) {
                @Override
                public void calcTuition() {
                }
            };
            String res = pIn.next();
            double fee = pIn.nextDouble();
            int credits = pIn.nextInt();
            if (res.equals("R")) {
                OnCampusStudent.setResidency(true);
            } else {
                OnCampusStudent.setResidency(false);
            }
            OnCampusStudent.setProgramFee(fee);
            OnCampusStudent.setCredits(credits);
            return OnCampusStudent;
        }

        private ArrayList<Student> readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
            readOnCampusStudent (in) ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            //info.add(type, id, lname, fname, resstat, prfee, credits);
            String fName = "p02-students.txt";
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fName));
            String studentType;
            while (in.hasNext()) {
               // studentList.add(type, id, lname, fname, resstat, prfee, credits);
                if ("C".equals(in.next())) {
                    studentList.add(readOnCampusStudent(in));
                }
                studentList.add(readOnlineStudent(in));
                in.nextLine();
            }
            in.close();
            return studentList;
        }

        private void writeFile(ArrayList<Student> pStudentList) throws FileNotFoundException {
            File file = new File("p02-tuition.txt");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
            for (Student s : pStudentList) {
                out.print(s.getId() + " " + s.getLName() + " " + s.getFName());
                out.printf("%.2f%n", s.getTuition());
            }
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

## Student Class with 2 sub-classes

```
public abstract class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
        private int mCredits;
        private String mFname;
        private String mLname;
        private int mId;
        private double mTuition;

        public Student(int pId, String pFname, String pLname) {
            mId=pId;
            mFname = pFname;
            mLname = pLname;
        }

    //Implement this method in the subclass
    //of student class
        public abstract void calcTuition();

    //Set credits of student
        public void setCredits(int pCredits) {
            mCredits = pCredits;
        }

    //Returns the credits of student
        public int getCredits() {
            return mCredits;
        }

    //Set first name
        public void setFname(String pFname) {
            mFname = pFname;
        }

    //Returns first name
        public String getFirstName() {
            return mFname;
        }

    //Set id
        public void setid(int pId) {
            mId = pId;
        }

    //Retunrns id
        public int getid() {
            return mId;
        }

    //Set last name
        public void setLname(String pLname) {
            mLname = pLname;
        }

    //Returns last name
        public String getLastName() {
            return mLname;
        }

    //Returns the tuition fee
        public void setTuition(double pTuition) {
            mTuition = pTuition;
        }

    //Returns the tuition fee
        public double getTuition() {
            return mTuition;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Student pStudnet) {
            if (getid() < pStudnet.getid()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (getid() > pStudnet.getid()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        int getId() {
            return mId;
        }

        String getLName() {
            return mLname;
        }

        String getFName() {
            return mFname;
        }

        void setResidency(boolean b) {
        }

        void setProgramFee(double fee) {
        }
    }

    abstract class onCampusStudent extends Student
    {
        boolean mResident;
        double mProgramFee;

        onCampusStudent(int pId, String pFname, String pLname)
        {
            super(pId,pFname,pLname);
        }
    }

    abstract class onlineStudent extends Student
    {
        boolean mResident;
        double mProgramFee;

        onlineStudent(int pId, String pFname, String pLname)
        {
             super(pId,pFname,pLname);
        }
    }
```

## Sorter Class

```
public class Sorter {

    public static final int SORT_ASCENDING = 0;
    public static final int SORT_DESCENDING = 1;

    /**
    * Sorts pList into ascending (pOrder = SORT_ASCENDING) or descending
    * (pOrder = SORT_DESCENDING) order using the insertion sort algorithm.
    */
    public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Student> pList, int pOrder) {
        for (int i = 1; i < pList.size(); ++i) {
            for (int j = i; keepMoving(pList, j, pOrder); --j) {
                swap(pList, j, j - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Returns true if we need to continue moving the element at pIndex until it
    * reaches its proper location.
    */
    private static boolean keepMoving(ArrayList<Student> pList, int pIndex, int pOrder) {
        if (pIndex < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        Student after = pList.get(pIndex);
        Student before = pList.get(pIndex - 1);
        return (pOrder == SORT_ASCENDING) ? after.compareTo(before) < 0 : after.compareTo(before) > 0;
    }

    /**
    * Swaps the elements in pList at pIndex1 and pIndex2.
    */
    private static void swap(ArrayList<Student> pList, int pIndex1, int pIndex2) {
        Student temp = pList.get(pIndex1);
        pList.set(pIndex1, pList.get(pIndex2));
        pList.set(pIndex2, temp);
    }
}
```

## TuitionConstants Class

```
public class TuitionConstants {
    public static final int ONCAMP_ADD_CREDITS = 350;
    public static final int MAX_CREDITS = 18;
    public static final int ONCAMP_NONRES_BASE = 12200;
    public static final int ONCAMP_RES_BASE = 5500;
    public static final int ONLINE_CREDIT_RATE = 875;
    public static final int ONLINE_TECH_FEE = 125;
}
```

## p02-students.txt

```
C 8230123345450 Flintstone Fred R 0 12 
C 3873472785863 Simpson Lisa N 750 18 
C 4834324308675 Jetson George R 0 20 
O 1384349045225 Szyslak Moe - 6
O 5627238253456 Flanders Ned T 3
```

Comment: question is not clear, please add more details.

Comment: You have more problems than just incompatible types in your code...

Comment: `readOnCampusStudent (in) ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();` - What the heck is this line?

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer the program has four classes but this is the point I get the error. If you want I can put up the four classes code.The program should read the contents of p02-students.txt and calculate the tuition for each student.The program should then write the tuition results to an output file named p02-tuition.txt formatted.

Comment: @D M that is what brings the error buddy..how should I put it?

Comment: @ Display Name What other problem is there?

Comment: I can tell it's wrong.  I can't really tell what you're all trying to do, so it's hard to say how to fix it.  You haven't even declared the `in` variable yet at that point; that's a few lines down.  I don't know what `readOnCampusStudent` is, either, or what it's doing on that line.

Comment: Divide the question into several parts.
1) Read the file and then print out the contents of the file on the console to check if the program is reading file correctly.
2) Calculate tuition and print out again on the console.
3) Last step, write on the another text file.

Comment: Please post all four classes. At this point, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer I just did

Comment: Working on it..

Comment: Can I see the contents inside the text file?

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer                                                                                     C 8230123345450 Flintstone Fred R 0 12 
C 3873472785863 Simpson Lisa N 750 18 
C 4834324308675 Jetson George R 0 20 
O 1384349045225 Szyslak Moe - 6
O 5627238253456 Flanders Ned T 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private ArrayList<Student> readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

        String fName = "p02-students.txt";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fName));

        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {

             String studentType = scan.next();

            if (studentType.equals("C")) {
                studentList.add(readOnCampusStudent(scan));
            } else {
                studentList.add(readOnlineStudent(scan));
            }

            scan.nextLine();
        }

        scan.close();
        return studentList;
    }
```

I didn't get the error you mentioned earlier, but I was getting input mismatch error because you weren't reading the data correctly.

For example, you were trying to store "8230123345450" in to an **int** variable. As per java standards, the value of **int** variable should be between 2147483647 and -2147483648. Therefore, I would suggest you to use a **long** type variable or another String type variable to store it.

```
private onCampusStudent readOnCampusStudent(Scanner pIn) {

        String id = pIn.next();

        String lname = pIn.next();

        String fname = pIn.next();

        System.out.println(id + " " + lname + " " + fname);
    }
```

I printed out the values, and it worked fine for every student. Don't forget to change the data type of **mid** variable in student class.

Comment: let me know if you're still facing issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the errors. I also got the input mismatch error and i did as you advised.Now am set to go.

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code are both in your main class:

`import static java.lang.System.in;`

`Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fName));`

You have two things called "in".  This is likely causing the error in question - it's getting confused as to whether it's the imported "in" (which is an InputStream) or the variable "in" (which is a Scanner.)  I suggest you not import java.lang.System.in and just type System.in when you want to use that one.  Then it won't conflict with your variable.

Comment: Alternatively, you could rename the variable so it isn't called "in".

Comment: Thank you for your help.